# Why am I unable to connect to ftp, or git or mysql server from my ubuntu 14.04 LTS computer?

Tags: networking, mysql, ftp, git

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I used to manage my ftp connections through FileZilla, and use git through terminal as well as mysql through terminal...

Then, today, nothing works.
I try to connect to my ftp server, and I get this:

```
Connecting to [::1]:21...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection 
refused by server", trying next address.
Status: Connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21...
Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

and when I run the networking configuration wizard, it only passes when I select the option :

**Get external IP address from the following URL:**
url : http://ip.filezilla-project.org/ip.php

Also, git responds with `connection refused`

mysql responds with `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xxx.xx' (110)`

Next thing I know, when I came to run `sudo apt-get update`,
many lines in the output are something like:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found [IP: ::1 80]
```

I don't understand, everything used to work just fine,

I've been offline for a week and when I came with a new router, this happened.

I added myself to the DMZ, nothing happened.
My router does not come with port forwarding, but I found that there is a functionality named `NAT ALG and Pass-Through` and there is FTP checked.

I removed the check from FTP, nothing happened, so I rechecked it as it used to.

I tested ftp with a Windows machine in my network and everything went smoothly, so it's not the router...

Any hints?

PS: NETIS-DL4310

And my network is a regular home network, and I am the client who is trying to connect to external servers.

Ping does work when I ping on the IPs, and I do connect to those servers from my Windows machine.

*If anyone can explain what is this ' ::1 ' IP, then please do provider us with an explaination.*

Comment: From yor description it is unclear what the network setup is. Where is the server (internet, at home), where is the client, where in between (or not) is the router? Further: can you ping, inside or to the outside, does your DNS still work?

Comment: Thank you for your remark, I'll add those informations in a minute

Comment: For ::1 see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost. Your networkd does not seem to be up and running at all. What is the output of
`ifconfig`, `route -n`, `nslookup 8.8.8.8`. Are you connected by ethernet or wifi? Why do you think you need either port forwarding or DMZ when all you want is to connect from this ubuntu box to the outside world?

Comment: I am connected by Wifi, and my network is actually running. I thought I needed DMZ or port forwarding, because I am actually accessing the internet, and I can not access the FTP, or GIT, or any connection to MySQL database outside my network...

And I thought there was something blocking it from the router, funny enough as I mentioned the Windows machine does all that with no problem, or could there be something wrong with my ip or local configurations?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution...

I have set a static IP from the "DHCP Static IP Configuration"..

and it worked!

I do not understand why the problem has popped in the first place, and why did this work at all, I just went by some friend's recommendations.

If someone understands what was the problem why did this solution solve it, please post it and I'll choose it as the answer.

Comment: Good you found a solution. It looks like your router is not configured as DHCP. Well, at least your Ubuntu does not get an address from it.

Comment: If you'd like too, a detailed answer with general solutions would close this question :)